# CodeIgniter No rows returned from get()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-abstraction

I've been messing with this for a few hours now.  It's got to be something dumb, but I'm just not seeing it.  Why does my db->get() not return any rows?  This is my first attempt at an MVC framework.  I've installed apache2, mysql, php5, and codeigniter in Ubuntu.  For some reason, I just can't seem to get the model to access the data in the database.

```
# cat config/database.php 
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['username'] = 'webuser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'webuser';
$db['default']['database'] = 'product';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

# cat models/productmodel.php 
<?php
    class Productmodel extends CI_Model {

            public function __construct() {
                    parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->database();
            }

            public function ListData() {

                    $query = $this->db->get("Fruit");

                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                            foreach ( $query->result() as $row ) {
                                    echo "VALUE: <BR>\n";
                            }
                    } else {
                            $string = $this->db->last_query();
                            echo "$string <BR>\n";
                    }

                    return $query->result();
            }
    }
?>

# cat controllers/productcontroller.php 
<?php
    class Productcontroller extends CI_Controller {
            public function index() {
                    $this->load->model('productmodel');

                    $data['query'] = $this->productmodel->ListData();

                    $data['title'] = 'MVC Test';
                    $data['heading'] = 'Data From product.Fruit';
                    $this->load->view('content', $data);
            }
    }
?>

# cat views/content.php 
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
    <?php foreach ($query AS $value) {echo "Value: $value <BR>\n"; } ?>
  </body>
</html>

# echo "SELECT * FROM product.Fruit" | mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u webuser --password=webuser
name      color   size
Apple      Red     1
Orange     Orange  1
Watermelon Green   3
Grape      Green   0
Cherry     Red     0
HoneyDew   Green   2
```

Comment: Does your error log report anything? Here is information on [where to find the PHP error log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log).

Comment: You mean to say that `$query = $this->db->get("Fruit");` does not return any results? That's impossible. What happens if you replace `db->get()` with `db->query('SELECT * FROM Fruit);`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    $data   = array();                                  #array declaration
    $query  = $this->db->get("Fruit");                  #actual get all query
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){                         #checking for the existence of rows
        $data   = $query->result_array();               #will fetch all the tuples in the data array 
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";die;      #print the data array and die
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as described [Here](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2009/05/Debugging-ActiveRecord-queries-in-CodeIgniter/)
debug with  `$this->db->last_query();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.It will give you both the data in the table and number of records the table contained.

```
public function your_method()
{      
        $this->db->select('*')->from('your_table');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $res['your_data']    = $query->result(); 
            $res['num_rows']     = $query->num_rows();

        }
        //if your_table contains data/records or not the following code will give you result in both the cases. 
        echo "<pre>";print_r($res);die; 

}
```